# Can't take a boolean value between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the following class to check first time launch of my application:

```
public class PrefManager 
{
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "dnq-welcome";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }
}
```

In my intro I use this check that works with no problem:

```
// Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
    launchHomeScreen();
    finish();
}
```

Now in my second activity, I want to continue check for a login process. So I have almost the same code but it's not working.

```
import eu.healthydev.quizhero.Intro.PrefManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
            if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "!isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

I get null exception. If i add

```
prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
```

then the third activity doesnt change the value of prefManager

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editUsername.getText().toString().trim())) {
                uploadUserData();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(NewUserActivity.this, GameChooseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
                finishAffinity();
            }
            else{
                FancyToast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this,"Nickname cannot be empty.",FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,FancyToast.ERROR,false).show();
            }
```

otherwise third activity works fine with no problem. So my question is, why to work in 2 of three activities? Any idea?
(if more code need just ask)

UPDATE

After many tries i manage to set the value as i need and now i have an extremely impossible event....:)

```
//check the current user
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                Intent userprofile = new Intent(this, UserProfile.class);
                startActivity(userprofile);
                FancyToast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch() User profile should run",FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT,FancyToast.ERROR,false).show();
            }
            else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));
                FancyToast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "New User should run", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
            }
        }
```

I m seeing the message "!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch() User profile should run" but NewUserActivity is starting again.! Completely lost with this case!

Comment: Can you add all code of your second activity where you get NullPointerException.

Comment: @p.alexey I added the needed part. I dont think need more than this as its a big activity contoling Google+, Facebook and Firebase auth

Comment: Hm... You forgot do this `prefManager = new PrefManager(this);` before call `prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()` :)

Comment: consider making the class methods static

Comment: @p.alexey check my edit. I had as you said, but then the third activity didnt change the value. If i have the initializatio, second works, third not. If i dont initialize, second throw null exception, third works.

Answer (score 0):

In your second Activity you need to create an instance of PrefManager.

Instead of

```
PrefManager prefManager;//null. 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //WARNING. prefManager is null. NullPointer exception is comming.
            if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "!isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
```

You can create an instance of PrefManager in onCreate method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);//instance. 
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            //ALL OK. prefManager is not null. NullPointerException is avoided.
            if (prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "!isFirstTimejoin.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I ve done it, but then its not working in the third activity. Actually this is the problem I have IntroActivity (runs @first launch) Main activity (check if firabase user has created profile or not) and NewUserActivity that runs only the first time. So all three need the isFirstTimeLaunch. If i instance in second activity, not works the third. If i dont instance in second works the third!

Comment: In which part of the code the "IsFirstTimeLaunch" value is updated from false to true?.

Comment: If you see my post, i have the third activity code. in onCreate prefManager = new PrefManager(this); Then onClick i set  prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false); But if i destroy the activity(third one)  when i launch the app again, the second activity is loaded again. (Supposed to not load as the value now is FALSE)